# Which has better performance: executing a Perl script from C++ via system call, or calling a DLL file?

Tags: c++, perl

I am new to C++ coding.

I wanted to execute a Perl script (that controls an equipment) inside a C++ Visual Studio Win32 application. I was wondering what would be the most optimized approach in this regards?

1. Call system function and execute that particular Perl file.
2. Create some kind of DLL and call that DLL inside my C++ code.

Option 2 I have never used, but I am willing to learn and implement if that's the best way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the "most optimized" approach is to [embed Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlembed.html) in your application.

Your second option is not really feasible, AFAIK. Since Perl is not compiled, your only other option would be to invoke the interpreter (e.g. through a `system()` or `exec()`-family call), as per your first option.

Now, there is quite a difference between embedding an interpreter in your code, and writing one line of code to call an external program, so you have to consider exactly how much optimization you need. The performance difference might even be minimal, so I strongly suggest that you try the easy way first, measuring your success.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Oystein that you're not likely to find a good way to compile the perl script into a shared library.

However, spawning perl from your C++ program isn't the only other option.  You could also pipe data between the two programs, use a socket to pass data between them, and other IPC methods.

Comment: I was not under the impression that the OP had any intents of sharing data between the C++ and Perl code - after all, a system call was suggested?

Comment: @Oystein: The default mode for perl is to process command line arguments if there are any, and read from stdin otherwise.  So using system might require a new process per command (he said equipment control), while piping might let a single instance of perl process a whole series of commands.

Answer (score -1):

In my backup tool I once tried invoking `system("perl script.pl")`, but it ran very slow on **Windows** (20-30 calls per second or so even though script.pl in a test benchmark did nothing). On **Linux** it was much, much quicker.